# Precise meaning of gross salary in a job vacancy announcement

Tags: salary

I would like to ask about the the precise meaning of the phrase:

> Gross Salary: up to 30,000 euros/year, health insurance benefits

means that the health insurance benefits are calculated on top of the 30,000 euros  or that they are included in the 30,000 euros ?

**Motivation:** I found this exact phrase in a job vacancy anouncement and since i am not a native speaker of english, i would like to know the precise meaning before applying.

Thank you in advance

**Edit:** The job vacancy announcement is for a job in Greece.

Comment: just out of curiosity: why the downvote ?

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but the correct answer might depend on the system in your country (meaning: your locality).

Comment: Country would be useful. Example in France : take off (roughly)23% of gross salary, and you'll get the net salary.

Comment: gazzz0x2z : it is about a job in Greece. Thanks for indicating that. I've edited the OP to add that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The health insurance is not part of the 30 salary. It is a benefit.

You should also get a pension.

Out of the 30 you will pay tax and national insurance in Europe

Comment: Yes, this is the correct answer.  You get 30K € as salary, but there may be various deductions depending on local law.

Comment: If you agree please accept the answer

Answer (score 3):

**Gross salary** in this context means the amount that the company will pay out, before taxes and other costs are deducted. Contrast that with **net salary**, which is the amount that you actually receive after taxes etc. are deducted. When people talk about salary, they're generally talking about gross salary because net salary tends to vary depending on personal circumstances (marital status, number of dependents, etc.).

How health insurance affects your net salary may depend on the particulars of the country that you're in. In the US, for example, employers and employees each pay a portion of the cost of health care; the employee's portion would typically be deducted from his/her gross salary while the employer's portion is entirely separate from salary.

If you're interested enough in the job that you're considering applying, there's no harm in asking a HR representative or the hiring manager to clarify anything that's in the ad.